# The use of Textblob for multiple domain tweets for sentiment

Tags: twitter, textblob

I'm building an application that analyze sentiment for news-related tweets in different domains, such as sports, disaster and technology, I'm using Textblob with the default mode (PatternAnalyzer). Does that provide a good sentiment even though domains are different? And how can I evaluate its performance? Or is it better to provide my own training data for each domain and train a classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textblob is a basic sentiment predictor and it wont be accurate. Its basic training model is trained on movie-review dataset which wont work efficiently for you. I would suggest you to create different datasets for each, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the site (textblob) mentioned that they use two methods one is PatternAnalyzer and the other one is the one trained on movie-review dataset, so how can I evaluate the PatternAnalyzer method?  http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_usage.html

Comment: PatternAnalyzer wont do any good.It uses just a word-weight mechanism.
http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-pattern.

To prove my point further -
http://textanalysisonline.com/pattern-sentiment-analysis

If you'll try out sentences like 'It look's good' and 'good' the output will be polarity (0.7) which is the weight given to the word good.

It's algo as per my understanding also uses a very basic negation detection mechanism (couldn't find any written note). If a polarity word has a negation word (not,no) it will add an opposite weight to it.